# Pra quê server o "@" dentro do printf da funçao solve

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void solve(int QTD_DISCOS, int origem, int destino, int temp)
{
  static int rank = 0;

  if (QTD_DISCOS > 0)
  {
    solve(QTD_DISCOS-1, origem, temp, destino);
    printf("%4d ) %c --> %c\n", ++rank, '@' + origem, '@' + destino);
    solve(QTD_DISCOS-1, temp, destino, origem);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int d;
  printf("Digite o numero de discos da Torre de Hanoi: \n");
  scanf("%d", &d);
  printf("A solucao de Hanoi eh: \n");
  solve(d, 1, 3, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Em C, '@' é um int. Mas, o tipo `char` é do tamanho de 1 byte.

```
main()
{
  char arroba = '@';

  printf("tamanho '@'  = %d\n", sizeof('@'));
  printf("tamanho char = %d\n", sizeof(arroba));

  return 0;
}
```

A saida do programa é:

```
leandro@macbook /tmp % ./a.out
tamanho '@'  = 4
tamanho char = 1
```

Logo, você pode adicionar com um inteiro. No seu exemplo:

```
'@' + 1 = 'A'
'@' + 2 = 'B'
'@' + 3 = 'C'
```

No printf, você pode formatá-lo utilizando `%c`, mas veja que pode truncar o resultado da soma. No programa de exemplo, não há esse problema.

Comment: acho que a resposta direta da questão deveria vir no começo. Todas as suas edições deram uma maior profundidade à resposta, mas acabou distanciando o conteúdo direto da dúvida do foco.